# Why is there a need to convert hexadecimal to RAW data format?(IoT project)

Tags: iot

I am doing IoT project to control AC remotely. I got the code from https://www.iotdesignpro.com/projects/universal-iot-based-ac-remote-that-can-control-your-ac-using-google-assistant this site. IR signal sends  hexadecimal value. When I am transmitting IR signal why do I have to convert it to raw data format and then transmit that? Why can't I send hexadecimal itself?

Answer (score 1):

Judging by the liberal use of `uint64ToString` what you are looking at is a textual representation of hexadecimal and not *actual* hexadecimal.

The text "**0x85**" as printed on screen or via a serial port is four characters, each character being 8 bits or 16 bits for UTF-16, and is not actually `0x85` in hex. Printed it would be 32-bits, the actual hex would be only 8 bits.

The conversion is done purely for human readability, printing the actual `0x85` value would result in [something that is not actually readable](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/85/index.htm) and may make serial consoles go weird.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Does the serial consoles goin weird has anything to do with baud rate because I was messing around changing baud rate the console started displaying weird stuff.

Comment: Displaying weird stuff due to different baud rates is because one side is expecting a speed different to the other. You see wrong characters because one side is only seeing random bits of the data rather than the complete stream, as it would with the correct speed on both sides.